# New to UX, what are the things to focus on UX design?

Tags: ux-designer, lean-ux

I was working in print design. Recently i switched into UX. So what are the things  I should focus on.

Answer (score 1):

User Interface (UI) designer:

- the *what* person
- deals primarily with the visual details, the graphic aspect of applications
- is more commonly familiar with only the static states of applications
- partially responsible for focusing the user's attention on elements
- keeps up with current trends and styles

User Experience (UX) practitioner:

- the *why* person
- many are not designers, and UX is not just about design
- has his or her hands in every aspect of the product's development
- is more of a coordinator, project manager and director
- they concern themselves with everything from the tone and voice of
  the copy, the information architecture, taxonomy, to the color and
  texture of the UI elements
- they focus on research, psychology, testing and advocacy
- the best UX'ers are the ones that constantly advocate for the user
  they ensure that everything is balanced and the experience doesn't
  lose out to other business interests (bottom-line), department
  conflicts (we need more advertising space) and other non-user minded
  things

There always got some one who vote and devote just try to gain it from social.

Comment: Although you'll find that there are basically UX Designer jobs (primarily focussed on design and software - and UX Researcher jobs (Primarily focussed on user research and psychology).  Some companies try to do cover both roles with the one person, but personally I think it's such a broad skill range that it's not covered properly.

Comment: @PhillipW agree!

Comment: @PhillipW Yeah you are correct. I have this issue, the company I work for officially claims I'm a "Interaction and UX designer", yet I'm also an information architect and visual designer.. even a little bit of front-end developing. It's called unicorn in this business :)

Comment: I've generally stuck to being an expert on people and the way they think. It has got easier since 2010 since there's more recognition that in a bigger organisation that you need different people to handle the overall UX process.